# Rails 6.1 uninstall bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

All the guides I've found are pre-webpacker, how can I make sure to completely remove bootstrap from a rails/webpacker app.

sidenote: I followed [this guide](https://stevepolito.design/blog/rails-6-bootstrap-4-webpacker-tutorial/) for installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `yarn remove <package>` to remove the package and you have to remove the bootstrap code manually which you've added.